# Jackson annotations ignored in Tomcat but work fine in JerseyTest

Tags: java, tomcat, jackson, jersey

I'm running a Jersey 2.x application in Tomcat 7. I'm using Jackson 2 with all the correct dependencies.

I wrote a basic test with `JerseyTest` to check my API. My jackson annotations work fine there. However, as soon as I deploy it in Tomcat, none of my Jackson annotations work.

Another interesting thing is that when I register a custom deserializer on the default Jersey `ObjectMapper`

```
private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(MyEntity.class, new MyEntityDeserializer());
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    mapper.registerModule(module);
    return mapper;
}
```

The deserializer is picked up in Tomcat. Just with annotations it's not.

The annotations I have tried are

```
@JsonCreator
@JsonDeserialize
@JsonSetter
```

I'm not quite sure where to start debugging this issue.

Comment: what annotations aren't working, can you share code?

Comment: @user7294900 I have updated the question. I have a feeling none of my jackson annotations work in Tomcat. They work fine with JerseyTest

Comment: are you specifying @JsonProperty before each field while using these annotations?

Comment: @sachinrai Only for the fields that require it. It's not so much that I am misusing jackson, because it works outside of Tomcat, but it's rather that for some reason the annotations are not picked up when the webapp is deployed. 

For example, my deserializer is actually hit when I manually create an instance of it as shown in my example. But with the annotation it is not created in runtime by Tomcat

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the entities I was referring to from my webapp were being compiled into a JAR, which were **not** reloaded by Tomcat. Restarting tomcat solved the issue.